# Determining which functions are one to one

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

So I know for sure that $x^3$ is one to one, being that the entire span of real number $y$'s can be found by some x and it passes the vertical line test. Graphically, its pretty clear. I know that $x^2$ is also one to one though not onto, since no negative $y$'s can be obtained. I don't have the same graphical intuition for options B, D, and E. How would I go about making that determiniation?

Comment: A function has to pass the *horizontal* line test to be one-to-one.  So $x\mapsto x^2$ isn't one-to-one.

Comment: $f(x)=x^2$ is not a one-to-one function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to look at the kernel for the not-so obvious ones. I should note that this works for only linear maps.

(b) The kernel is $\{ (x,x,x) \}$, so no not injective

(c) No, clearly.

(d) The kernel of this is $\{(x,-x) \}$, so no not injecive

(e) Yes the kernel of this is trivial (can you see why?)

Answer (score 0):

Hints: For (B), consider $f(x,x,x)$.

For (D), consider $f(x,-x)$

For (E), find $x$ and $y$ given $x+y = a$ and $x-y = b$.